# Yii CListView beforeAjaxUpdate function signature

Tags: php, javascript, sorting, yii

Need some help with `CListView`.

In this widget exists a property `beforeAjaxUpdate`, just like in `CGridView` but
with one difference - this property invokes JS function with only one param `ID`
of widget:

```js
function(id)
```

But in CGridView this function has two params, the second is `OPTIONS` of AJAX request:

```js
function(id, options)
```

So, does anyone know how to realize the same functionality of `beforeAjaxUpdate` with two options in JS function of `CListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at giving additional options for the ajax request, there are 2 options in my opinion:

Either use the members provided by the Class to set the options : 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#properties

Or extend CListView and adjust https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/zii/widgets/CListView.php#L230 
so you can load extra options yourself.

The way this is written made it so that all the common oprions can be set with public members of the class.

Comment: I think you have missed the point. The OP is after the ajax options (i.e. properties of jQuery.ajax()), which is available in CGridView's beforeAjaxUpdate function.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't available, but modifying jquery.yiilistview.js to send it to the beforeAjaxUpdate function works. This isn't ideal for most people of course, as it means altering the core, which should be avoided. I will submit a bug and patch to Yii, if there isn't already one in the pipeline.